# com:android:support:percent:23.3.0 library fails in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

sir：
I meet this problem:installation `com:android:support:percent:23.3.0` library fails in `Android Studio`,and fault is description as :my  `compileSdkVersion` is `19` and `this library` is require above `21`, how can i solve it? pls advise me, thanks you very much for you suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Edit you `build.gradle` file (the one under app/ directory), and simply change the compiled sdk version as requested :

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 23
    ...
}
```

You may be required to change other variables too. Then choose 'Sync Now' to validate.